# AttributeError: module 'ocrmypdf' has no attribute 'ocr'

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am using ocrmypdf library for the conversion of scanned pdf to searchable pdf but I got this error.

This is the code that I am currently running

```
import ocrmypdf
ocrmypdf.ocr('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset 2020/OCR/1081975.pdf', 'output.pdf')
```

Error :-

```
AttributeError: module 'ocrmypdf' has no attribute 'ocr'
```

Comment: Do you have any files named `ocrmypdf`? Including the script in question.

Comment: No, i didn't have any file name ocrmypdf

Comment: From the [docs](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html): _"On Windows and macOS, the script that calls `ocrmypdf.ocr()` must be protected by an “ifmain” guard (`if __name__ == '__main__'`). If you do not take at least one of these steps, process semantics will prevent OCRmyPDF from working correctly."_

Comment: I already check it, but nothing happen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I install this library using the following commands on google collab and it's work:-

1. `apt install ocrmypdf`
2. `pip3 install git+https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF.git`
3. `pip3 install pluggy`